# Hot question but locked

Tags: support, hot-questions, locked-questions

I was going through the hot question list and found this question

[Why can't my program compile under Windows 7 in French?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780466/why-cant-my-program-compile-under-windows-7-in-french)

This question is locked and it is in the hot question list. Is that right ? If it is locked then it shouldn't be part of hot questions or it should be unlocked.

Comment: I would disagree with this in general (e.g. locked due to offtopic comments") but as this is a historical lock you may have a point

Comment: Historical locks for questions asked yesterday probably weren't something the developers considered for even a second.

Comment: The alternative is deletion.  Pick one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I am not sure if it should be deleted or locked, but in both cases should it be part of Hot questions ?

Comment: I think a historical lock for an april fools post is entirely appropriate. It's not relevant anymore today, but it is worth preserving.

Comment: I think the lock fits perfectly: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Apologies, my intention was not to gang up on you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... I see no personal attacks. All I see is "possibly off-topic." You, as a 100k+ user, take closing personally?

Comment: @hichris123: Not a closing, no. This question (which is about doing a lot more than closing a question) and certain comments on the answers (which now seem to have been removed), yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I unlocked it, closed it, and locked it again.  That should take it out of the hot list.

Comment: Isn't closing the question enough? I'm quite sure closed question won't appear in the hot questions list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard closing the question will remove it from the hot questions list.  However, this particular question had a significant number of close/reopen cycles which the lock solves.  The issue was that an open, but locked question wasn't removed from the hot questions (which probably should get listed as a bug/oversight).

Comment: @ShadowWizard At Stack Overflow we, and by "we" I mean the moderators, hate fun.  Locking it is necessary to prevent the teeming masses of unwashed users from reopening it.

Comment: @MichaelT oh, guess you're right. Feel free to start such feature request, I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: @Pollyanna do you have invisible diamond I missed? ;) Anyway I got the point, took me a while to understand it was all a joke.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I'm just wishing the moderators were more lenient for fun. I have absolutely no interest in becoming one, though, so I can't give them too much trouble.

Comment: I don't really think it's a bug, either. The question was hot, recently. I don't think most of the stuff that shows up in the list is necessarily representative of good questions for the sites they're on, but the list isn't labelled "great, on-topic, well-written network questions".

Comment: consider doing the same to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789277/unicoin-mining-and-canvas-clicking (same thing, locked open and in the hot list, quite confusing for lemmings I guess)

Answer (score -4):

I find this prejudicial. This was a real problem that I faced. Who are you to assume/assert that it is anything but that? :( As far as I can tell, it fits *all* of the criteria for an on-topic programming question.

If you think a problem is too "basic" or "obvious" then that's your right, but jumping to the conclusion that the question must only be for "fun" *and proposing punitive measures against it*, just because you already happen to know the answer is, in my view, totally in contrast to the purpose of this site.